# Checking for library existence on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: c, shared-libraries, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur, mach-o

Is there a way of replicating the behaviour of `_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path` that will work on both MacOS Big Sur as well as MacOS Catalina?

---

##### My first attempt (using dlopen)

```c
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int library_exists(const char* path) {
    void* handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (handle == NULL) return 0;
    dlclose(handle);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int result;
    char* path;

    path = "/usr/lib/libc.dylib";
    result = _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(path);
    printf("_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(%s) == %d", path, result);
    result = library_exists(path);
    printf("library_exists(%s) == %d", path, result);

    path = "libc.dylib";
    result = _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(path);
    printf("_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(%s) == %d", path, result);
    result = library_exists(path);
    printf("library_exists(%s) == %d", path, result);
}
```

Output:

```
_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(/usr/lib/libc.dylib) == 1
library_exists(/usr/lib/libc.dylib) == 1
_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(libc.dylib) == 0
library_exists(libc.dylib) == 1
```

This is pretty close, except "libc.dylib" has different behaviour when passed to the 2 functions.

#### Background

MacOS Big Sur removed shared libraries from the file system, and placed them into a cache instead. The function _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path has been made available in <mach-o/dyld.h> along with this change.

[MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1 changenotes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes)

> *New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache. (62986286)*

I want a portable binary that checks for the existence of shared libraries on MacOS Catalina or MacOS Big Sur without the need for recompilation for a specific version of MacOS. If we reference _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path and attempt to compile on MacOS Catalina - compilation will fail. I want it to have the same behaviour as `_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path`.

Comment: What's wrong with dlopen? That's what you quoted tells you to use, and it's portable well beyond MacOS

Comment: dlopen is fine, but I'm working on a PR to make CPython binaries more portable across MacOS versions. Currently `_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path` is beinged used (which causes portability issues). If I use dlopen in my PR, the behavior of ctypes.util.find_library will change slightly - enough to break a couple of tests.

Comment: Of course I could change the tests to conform to the new version of ctypes.util.find_library, but then this change in behavior might break or change the behavior of peoples Python-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix `dlopen` by setting a bunch of environment variables... but you have to spawn a new process.

`man dlopen` has a more exhaustive description, but basically what you're seeing is a fallback effect because `libc.dylib` is just a "leaf name" and dyld searches a bunch of paths specified by environment variables for that library.

The following environment variables influence this behaviour:

- `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
- `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
- `DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX`

If not set, then the two `FALLBACK` ones default to some system paths - the manpage is not quite up to date on this, but the exact values can include the following paths or a subset thereof, based on flags set by the kernel:

- `/usr/local/lib`
- `/usr/lib`
- `/Library/Frameworks`
- `/System/Library/Frameworks`

`DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX` is a bit different, but if you set it to `.dylib`, then `dlopen("libc")` will succeed, so that's unwanted too.

You can disable all fallback behaviour by setting those environment variables to an empty string.

So if you call your code above like `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH='' ./test`, it will work as expected:

```
_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(/usr/lib/libc.dylib) == 1
library_exists(/usr/lib/libc.dylib) == 1
_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(libc.dylib) == 0
library_exists(libc.dylib) == 0
```

However, if you do a `setenv("DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH", "", 1);` in your code, you'll find that to not work. The reason for that is that dyld only looks at environment variables on process initialisation, anything after that is ignored.

Here's a working example with `execve`:

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

int library_exists(const char* path) {
    void* handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (handle == NULL) return 0;
    dlclose(handle);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int result;
    char* path;

    const char *vars[] = { "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH", "DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH", "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH", "DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH", "DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX" };
    char fail = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        char *v = getenv(vars[i]);
        if(!v || *v != '\0')
        {
            fail = 1;
            setenv(vars[i], "", 1);
        }
    }
    if(fail)
    {
        return execve(argv[0], (char*const*)argv, environ);
    }

    path = "/usr/lib/libc.dylib";
    result = _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(path);
    printf("_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(%s) == %d\n", path, result);
    result = library_exists(path);
    printf("library_exists(%s) == %d\n", path, result);

    path = "libc.dylib";
    result = _dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(path);
    printf("_dyld_shared_cache_contains_path(%s) == %d\n", path, result);
    result = library_exists(path);
    printf("library_exists(%s) == %d\n", path, result);
}
```